# Images fail to open when serving through PHP: "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x0a 0x0a"

Tags: php, http-headers, mime-types, rhel7

Having trouble getting file downloads to work.  Using PHP7 and Apache 2.4.6.

The file is presented to the browser with the correct MIME type and size.  When I attempt to open that file:

[image]

The file has the following permissions:

```
[user@box images]# ll 20180814170259999.jpg 
-rw-r-----. 1 apache apache 58405 Aug 14 17:02 20180814170259999.jpg
```

`file -i` shows the following:

```
[user@box images]# file -i 20180814170259999.jpg 
20180814170259999.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary
```

Here is the code used to present the file to the browser:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . "20180814170259999.jpg"); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . 58405);                 
readfile('/var/www/images/20180814170259999.jpg');
```

- I'm not showing any errors in Apache's error log.
- If I download the file over sftp, it opens just fine.
- The same error happens regardless of browser used.
- Changing Content-Type to `image/jpeg` makes no difference - same
  error as above.

**What could be going on to cause images not to display correctly?**

Comment: I usually see jpg Content-Type as `image/jpeg` instead of `application/octet-stream`. Maybe that will help?

Comment: No dice, still get the same 'could not load image' error.

Comment: `0xa` is hexadecimal for the number `10` which is the code for ascii `\n`. So check if your script has some new lines before the `<?php` tag.

Comment: Looks like two newlines are showing...

Comment: That's it - if you want to put that as the answer I'll hook you up.

Comment: a coder, Can you write, what happened? I have similar problem, but i have no idea where to find problem with number 0x20 0x20 - doubled 32.. and it's spacebar... But i have no idea where to find this lost treasure...